# Proof of the ABC conjecture - how feasible would it be to automate some of the deciphering of Shinichi Mochizuki’s proof?

Tags: mathematical-writing, mathematical-software, abc-conjecture

This is a question I will come back to. I am very interested in Shinichi Mochizuki’s proof, and in particular, the idiosyncrasies of his notation, which I understand to be at the root of why it is taking so long to verify it's correctness. (Please correct me if I am wrong here) Also, why would one create one's own notation for solving a problem? Just a thought.

My question, which is encapsulated in the title, is - how feasible would it be to automate some of the deciphering of Shinichi Mochizuki’s proof?

Perhaps this question is naive, but I would be interested to hear thoughts on the topic.

Comment: My understanding is that we are nowhere near being able to do this, but I'll let someone else confirm this (proof formalization/verification isn't actually my area).

Comment: I know nothing about Mochizuki's proof of abc, but I find it difficult to think that the difficulties of communicating it to the mathematical community lie importantly in a matter of notation (such as the work of Gottlob Frege). Rather, I think it is taking so long for mathematicians to grasp Mochizuki's argument because it is incredibly sophisticated and based on putting together a huge amount of new mathematical concepts.

Comment: It is better communication between human beings that is required, not the use of computers (which are programmed by humans as well).  Note that 4 years later, there has not been any work by anyone which uses insights from the IUT ideas to prove something else (even Dimitrov's "effective" improvement treated the IUT work as a black box).  This is unprecedented for a claimed breakthrough in mathematics at this level of significance, and conveys the status of the effort to communicate essential ideas (setting aside if the proof is correct).